# Timesheets on SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I've been tasked with developing a timesheet application in sharepoint. Currently we use spreadsheets with a standard list of categories and then we add various subcategories/projects/tasks we are working on and our hours.

My question is do you think this type of application can be built using sharepoint using the standard lists and items in sharepoint without writing code?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely YES. This can be achieved using  out of the box SharePoint functionality or even InfoPath (there is a guide on it here https://www.accelebrate.com/library/sharepoint-timesheet-form). The solution should be straightforward.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: lol, I would expect this kind of comment in 1999 :) archive.org

Comment: Hah, you're right. However the images were broken. Luckily somehow it's still on their site under a different folder: https://www.accelebrate.com/library/tutorials/sharepoint-timesheet-form